# BitmapEncoder Save Not Supported

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-ziparchive, bitmapencoder

I have the following code and I can't see anything wrong, any ideas on what the problem could be?

```
private static string SaveBaseImage( ZipArchive arc, DBImage image, int imageIndex )
{
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(image.Data))
    {
        var bmp = BitmapFrame.Create(mem);
        //var bmp = BitmapFrame.Create(m‌​em, BitmapCreateOptions.‌​None, BitmapCacheOption.On‌​Load);
        var codex = bmp.Decoder.CodecInfo;

        var filename = $"{imageIndex}{codex.FileExtensions}";
        var imagezip = arc.CreateEntry(filename,CompressionLevel.Optimal));
        using (var imagestream = imagezip.Open())
        {
            SaveImage( bmp, imagestream);
        }
        return filename;
    }
}

private static void SaveImage(BitmapFrame data, Stream saveStream)
{
    var codex = data.Decoder.CodecInfo;
    var encoder = BitmapEncoder.Create(codex.ContainerFormat);
    encoder.Frames.Add(data);
    encoder.Save(saveStream);
}
```

when I run it throws

> System.NotSupportedException occurred   HResult=-2146233067
>
> Message=Specified method is not supported.   Source=PresentationCore
>
> StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.Save(Stream stream)
>          at FileFormatters.Export.SaveImage(BitmapFrame data, Stream saveStream)
>
> InnerException: null

The MSDN page says

> NotSupportedException :The Frames value that is passed to the encoder is null.
>
> NotSupportedException :The Frames count is less than or equal to zero.

However frames count is 1 and data is not null

further info

```
arc declared as using (ZipArchive arc = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
image.Data is byte[]
codex.FriendlyName = "PNG Decoder"
encoder.CodecInfo.FriendlyName = "PNG Encoder"
```

Comment: Try to immediately load the bitmap from the MemoryStream by `var bmp = BitmapFrame.Create(mem, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);` Besides that, couldn't you just write the original `image.Data` to the archive?

Comment: @Clemens thanks for your help, unfortunately that was the first thing i thought of had no effect at all, as for skipping the decode i'm afraid not, as the next operation is to draw a strokes collection on top of the frame and save that as a 2nd image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be necessary to write the image buffer to an intermediate MemoryStream, before it can be written to a ZipEntry Stream:

```
private static void SaveImage(BitmapFrame data, Stream saveStream)
{
    var encoder = BitmapEncoder.Create(data.Decoder.CodecInfo.ContainerFormat);
    encoder.Frames.Add(data);

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        memoryStream.CopyTo(saveStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: So bitmap encoders don't support compressed streams? that would be useful information to include in the MSDN page